# How to parse a JSON file into a Ruby object

Tags: json, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to make a function that reads from a JSON file and parse it into an object, given the following rspec, but it gives me this error:

```
NoMethodError:undefined method `from_json' for Recipe:Class
```

This is lib/recipe.rb:

```
require 'json'

class Recipe
  attr_accessor :title, :description, :ingredients, :cook_time, :featured

  def initialize(title:, description:, ingredients:, cook_time:, featured:)
    @title = title
    @description = description
    @ingredients = ingredients
    @cook_time = cook_time
    @featured = featured 
  end

  def from_json(file)
    recipe = JSON.parse(json)
    Recipe.new(recipe)
  end
end
```

And my rspec:

```
 it 'Converts a json into an objeto from recipe type' do
recipe = Recipe.from_json('data/pudim.json')

    expect(recipe.class).to eq Recipe
    expect(recipe.title).to eq 'Pudim'
    expect(recipe.description).to eq 'O melhor pudim da sua vida!'
    expect(recipe.ingredients).to eq 'Leite condensado, ovos e leite'
    expect(recipe.cook_time).to eq 80
    expect(recipe.featured).to eq true
  end
```

This is data/pudim.json:

```
{
  "title": "Pudim",
  "description": "O melhor pudim da sua vida!",
  "ingredients": "Leite condensado, ovos e leite",
  "cook_time": 80,
  "featured": true
}
```

Comment: It seems like `Json.parse(json)` should be `JSON.parse(file)`.

Comment: changed it to JSON, still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to call a class method, but you have an instance method in your class.

Given this, you could try to change this method to `self.from_json(file)`.